# Windows Update fails with error 0x80070057 (Windows 10 Pro 21H2) - tried everything

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Just upgraded from 8.1 Pro via a mounted ISO to Win 10 Pro (21H2, 19044.1706, Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0).

Everything seems to work fine apart from Windows Update. It sees the updates but fails to download them saying

> *There were problems downloading some updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this, try searching the web or contacting support for help. This error code might help: (0x80070057)*

I tried everything specified in [this old Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/2tlzy0/9926_windows_update_0x80070057_error/) as well as a ton of other thinks found online, and my own registry investigations, all to no avail. See below.

In between trying different things, I was restarting the Windows Update service, and then also restarting the machine (just in case).

What's really bugging me is that Windows Update reports that "Some settings are managed by your organization" and lists them. Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzacP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e46YX.png

... but the thing is that my group policy is all on defaults! In gpedit.msc everything is on "Not configured" everywhere. Where does it get that list of settings from the 2nd screenshot?

I also did a "gpupdate /force"

I also did a "sfc /scannow"

I also ran the Windows Update Troubleshooter.

I then also checked some registry entries, for example:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Update\UpdateServiceUrl]
"Behavior"=dword:00012020
"GPBlockingRegKeyPath"="Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\WindowsUpdate"
"GPBlockingRegValueName"="WUServer"
"mergealgorithm"=dword:00000003
"policytype"=dword:00000001
"value"="CorpWSUS"
"wnfStateName1"=dword:a3bd2875
"wnfStateName2"=dword:13920028
```

I tried changing CorpWSUS to WSUS or to an empty string. No dice.

I also checked:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UpdatePolicy\PolicyState]
"DeferQualityUpdates"=dword:00000001
"DeferFeatureUpdates"=dword:00000001
"BranchReadinessLevel"="CBB"
"IsDeferralIsActive"=dword:00000001
"IsWUfBConfigured"=dword:00000000
"IsWUfBDualScanActive"=dword:00000000
"UseUpdateClassPolicySource"=dword:00000000
"SetPolicyDrivenUpdateSourceForFeatureUpdates"=dword:ffffffff
"SetPolicyDrivenUpdateSourceForQualityUpdates"=dword:ffffffff
"SetPolicyDrivenUpdateSourceForDriverUpdates"=dword:ffffffff
"SetPolicyDrivenUpdateSourceForOtherUpdates"=dword:ffffffff
"QualityUpdatesDeferralInDays"=dword:00000000
"FeatureUpdatesDeferralInDays"=dword:0000001e
"PolicySources"=dword:00000002
```

Tried changing DeferQualityUpdates and DeferFeatureUpdates to 0, and even delete them entirely, to see if WU still says they are set by policy. It still does.

Apart from the Update download errors, it bugs me that it says there are policy settings managing some settings, when gpedit shows all are set on "not configured".

Can anyone suggest a fix? ... other than wipe and install Win10 fresh, I can't afford that.

Comment: "0x80070057 error code means that Windows ran into a storage issue. Possibly, your hard drive or SSD didn't have enough space left to download or copy files.">>>>>>https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-windows-update-error-0x80070057/

Comment: Your feature update deferment is set to 30 days. CBB was discontinued 5 years ago in 2017.

Comment: None of those values are “default” or the values I would expect from a policy that was configured as “not configured” Yes; I realize that’s part of the problem but something’s settling those keys to those values. Provide screenshots of the local group policy editor, something tells me, you’re not even connected to an Active Directory domain. If you are connected to an AD domain [edit] your question to specify that fact.

Comment: `BranchReadinessLevel` being set to `CCB` is likely part of the problem, set it to `CB` instead.

Comment: @Moab no such problem (almost 1TB free)

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for replying! Not part of any AD (and win8.1 wasn't either). I could show screenshots of the full gpedit, but I'd like to think you believe me they are all on "Not configured". Also, I tried deleting the entire key `HLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UpdatePolicy\PolicyState` and rebooted, and it still shows the same policy settings in the win update panel. I can't explain where it reads it from. Doing a reg search for `BranchReadinessLevel` it only pops up in two places (once as value in my post, and then as key in `HLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Update`).

Comment: @Ramhound I can confirm that the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UpdatePolicy\PolicyState` did not exist in the win8.1 installation which was upgraded, so it was added during the win10 upgrade. Even so, I still don't understand where it reads it from given I tried deleting it entirely and it still sees those "administrator policy set" values.

Comment: @Ramhound ... believe it or not, I tracked it down to having a persistent subst drive on drive letter B:. I have B:, T:, X:, Z: all being persistent subst drives, but only B: creates issues. By persistent I mean they are DoS Devices in registry in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]` ... Win8.1 had no issues with this. Perhaps it's a bug introduced in Win10, because I tried upgrading to Win11 and it had exactly the same issue and same error. If not, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what "subst drive" is, if you think it's relevant, edit your question with the required information to better explain yourself.

Comment: I will edit the question when I am certain I fully isolated the issue. 
p.s. subst is an old command allowing to map any folder to a drive letter. Been around since DoS days. Seems Win10 and Win11 have a bug for A: and B: even though they allow them to be subst'ed. Win8.1 has no issues.

Answer (score 1):

The tip in your comment worked for me, so I'm posting it as an answer for better visibility (I almost missed it after following your link to the Reddit post suggesting some registry tweaks).

I had the issue in a VirtualBox machine after sharing a folder and mounting it on drive `B:` within the machine. Removing the shared folder so I didn't have anything mounted on drive `B:` solved the issue.

I'm not sure why Windows would have this behavior-- since it's proprietary, the only way to know may be to ask Microsoft. I did find [references](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/74935-using-b-even-drive-letters.html) to other quirks with `A:` and `B:` drives, such as not being indexed for search. (Not indexing removable drives would make sense, but failing to install updates when they're attached doesn't make sense.)

---

In case the issue isn't a drive being mounted on `A:` or `B:`, I'll also include the tips from the aforementioned [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/2tlzy0/9926_windows_update_0x80070057_error/). In the Registry Editor, set the following two values:

- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX] "IsConvergedUpdateStackEnabled"=dword:00000000
- [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings] "UxOption"=dword:00000000

For reference, on my VM where I hadn't modified these settings before, `UxOption` was already set to 0, but `IsConvergedUpdateStackEnabled` was previously set to 1. I did change it back to 1 after setting it to 0 didn't fix the issue, and the updates still worked once I removed the problematic drive mapping, so this registry key trick might be outdated now, but it could still be worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I got busy and didn't post an actual answer. The bug is definitely in persistent mapping of A: or B: drive letters. Mapping them persistently in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]` also triggers the bug. Mapping them after user-login, by executing `subst B: C:\folder` won't trigger the bug.

It's worth reporting to Microsoft but I didn't find where to report it ... maybe you will have more luck?

p.s. The registry keys you mentioned have nothing to do with it if you have persistent A: or B: mapped. It's a waste of time tinkering those.